# What is a Javascript test framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

This could be a stupid question. Jasmine, Qunit, Mocha, Unit.js, etc - as far I as I know are Javascript test frameworks. But what is a Javascript test framework? What it is for actually? Is it any different from these Javascript frameworks below?

```
ember.js
backbone
require.js
```

Jasmine,

```
describe('Hello world', function() {
  it('says hello', function() {
    expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
  });
});
```

It seems like that is what node.js does, isn't?

What do you need to **test**?

Comment: ember and backbone are mv* frameworks. require is a module/packaging system. i don't think node defines the jasmine structure unless you include it. you should test what you feel is relevant.

Comment: @mplungjan `rep_built_on_questons != rep_built_on_answers`

Comment: reputation-build-earlier === only-reputation-build-earlier

Comment: this is way too broad of a question.

Comment: ember, backbone keep your your code clean and avoids spaghetti code (usually seen in javascript) through the mvc(mv*) pattern .jasmine is a unit testing framework that allows you to unit test whatever you develop using these frameworks.

Comment: This question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hex494D49 amazing no-one told him in any of his 700 questions :)))

Comment: @mplungjan Well, there are even better candidates for a tron. Look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/users/143030/jasondavis. Marvelous ;) SO is full of nonsense.

Comment: Tron? I remarkably do not recognise the derogative here ;)

Answer (score 2):

(Short overview)

A test framework is a set of tools that allows you to test the functionality of your code (in this case your Javascript code).

It allows you to test certain functions and check if the output/result matches your expectations.
They allow you to test certain conditions and how your code react on that, like missing or unset variables, unexpected data in your variables and so on.

And one of the advantages is the test automation. This allows you to run a bunch of test automatically and it will give you result if every single test. This way you can see which test fails after you made  some changes in your code.

Also you should consider reading the link `mplungjan` provided.

(If I missed something mandatory to say, then leave a comment, I will add that)